# How to mockup TWebRequest/TIdHTTPAppRequest?

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, indy, dunit

I have a function that accept a `TWebRequest` by argument, eg.:

```
function foo(const request: TWebRequest ): boolean;
```

how can i create a `TWebRequest` and set some property like:

- Host
- ServerPort
- QueryFields
- ContentFields

I have tried:

```
var
  aWebRequest: TWebRequest;
begin
  aWebRequest := TWebRequest.Create;
```

but on creation Delphi raise an exception:

> First chance exception at $XXXXXXXX. Exception class EAbstractError
>   with message 'Abstract Error'.

the descendant is `TIdHTTPAppRequest`, but it require:

```
constructor TIdHTTPAppRequest.Create(
  AThread: TIdContext; 
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; 
  AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo
);
```

each argument require other object etc etc.

there is a simple way (eg. third party unit, unknown snippet or trick) for mockup a request for unit test purpose?

Answer (score 2):

`EAbstractError` usually means that you are trying to instantiate generic abstract class (e.g. `TStrings`) instead of it's descendant that contains required implementations (e.g. `TStringList`). So you need to find the `TWebRequest` descendant and use it instead.

For mocking purposes you could try to write your own "empty" descendant, but I doubt that will work as expected.

Comment: the descendant is TIdHTTPAppRequest but it require tons of other object dependencies...

Comment: Give it another day or two - maybe others will answer better.